# How can I speed up full calendar load times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I use full calendar on my website, and I've found that it is loading progressively slower as more events are added over time. It's gotten to the point where it takes 6-7 seconds to display the events after you hit the page.

I've tried a number of different tweaks to help speed things up, all to no avail. Here is the code I use to load the events:

```
$startdate = $_GET['start'];
$enddate = $_GET['end'];
$location = $_GET['location'];

$calendar = mysql_query('SELECT *, jobs.id as jobid, jobs.workOrder as jobWorkOrder, jobs.serviceType as serviceType, jobs.status as jobstatus, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(jobs.start_date) AS jobDate FROM jobs JOIN clients ON clients.id = client_id WHERE jobs.status <> 2 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "'. $enddate . '" AND jobs.location = "'.$location.'"');

$calendar_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($calendar)) {
    $jobrecurringtype = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT frequency FROM jobs_recurring WHERE id = "' . $row['recurring_id'] . '"'));

    //check for first-time jobs
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(jobs.id) AS amount
            FROM jobs
            WHERE client_id = "' . $row['client_id'] . '"
            AND start_date < "' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $row['jobDate']) . '"';
    $jobs = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));

    if($jobrecurringtype['frequency'] == '') { //non-recurring jobs 

        if(strpos($row['serviceType'],'fix it') === true){//add fix-it colors
        switch (jobNeedsProviders($row['jobid'])) {
            case false:
                $status = 'fix-it-confirmed';
                break;
            case true:
                $status = 'fix-it-unconfirmed';
                break;
        }
        } else {
        switch (jobNeedsProviders($row['jobid'])) {
            case false:
                $status = (($jobs['amount'] == 0) ? 'first-time-confirmed' : 'standard-confirmed');
                break;
            case true:
                $status = (($jobs['amount'] == 0) ? 'first-time-unconfirmed' : 'standard-unconfirmed');
                break;
        }
        }//end else


    } else { // Recurring jobs
        switch (jobNeedsProviders($row['jobid'])) {
            case false:
                if($row['dateAdded'] > '2010-11-01' && $jobs['amount'] == 0) {$status = 'first-time-confirmed';} else {$status = strtolower($jobrecurringtype['frequency']) . '-confirmed';}
                break;
            case true:
                if($row['dateAdded'] > '2010-11-01' && $jobs['amount'] == 0) {$status = 'first-time-unconfirmed';} else {$status = strtolower($jobrecurringtype['frequency']) . '-unconfirmed';}
                break;
        }
    }

    $recurring = ($row['recurring_id'] != 0 && $row['recurring_overridden'] != 1 ? 'recurring' : '');

    if($row['businessName'] != ''){$title = stripslashes($row['businessName']);}else{$title = stripslashes($row['firstName']) . ' ' . stripslashes($row['lastName']);}

    $calendar_array[] = array(
        'id' => stripslashes('job' . $row['jobid']),
        'title' => $title,
        'start' => $row['start_date'],
        'end' => date("Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hour", strtotime($row['start_date']))),
        'className' => array($status, $recurring, $row['jobWorkOrder']),
        'url' => "/manage/jobs_manage.php?jobmanage=1&jobedit=1&id=" . $row['jobid'],
        'allDay' => false);
}
    print json_encode($calendar_array);
}

function jobNeedsProviders($id){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT SUM(IF(provider_id=0,1,0)) AS fillers, COUNT(provider_id) AS totalProviders FROM `job_providers` WHERE job_id = ' . $id));
    if($row['fillers'] > 0 || $row['totalProviders'] == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm running a number of DB queries from within the while loop, and I suspect this may be the source of my issues. I'm not sure what alternative approach I can take to solve this, however. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add some benchmarking to determine what are the slowest steps

Comment: Instead of `mysql` use `mysqli` or `PDO`, both of them have prepare statements, this is a great thing when using the same query many times like you do in your while loop.

Comment: Like @Dagon said, I would first check the query, the time it takes to create all of the events, then the time it takes to render the events using fullcalendar.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about checking that?

Comment: To check the query, you can analyze your execution plan: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html. To check approximate php times I would just echo the the time it takes to create your calendar array. To check fullcalendar I would add javascript logging (ex: console.log()) before and after fullcalendar is called. Between those things you should be able to find your bottle neck. Also @Perry made a good point about you looping through and querying a bunch of times, something to look at.